Using catchfile with macro as filename
I am trying to use the catchfile package to read the contents of a file. At this stage, all I want is a macro that will take some name and number, say "log123.456" and read the contents of "log.txt" into a variable (for future processing with xstring).
I wrote a macro which takes "log123.456" as input and recursively removes the "123.456", returning "log":
\newcommand{\removenumber}[1]{\StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastchar]\StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\gobbled]\StrDel{\gobbled}{.}[\tempdelchar]\IfInteger{\lastchar}{\removenumber{\tempdelchar}}{#1\lastchar}}

(Apologies for formatting. I don't want to risk introducing line breaks which will break my code)
This works. If I call \removenumber{log123.456}.txt it outputs "log.txt", as expected. The problem starts when I try to use this as the filename in CatchFileDef. I have the following test macro:
\newcommand{\getlog}[1]{#1 \removenumber{#1}.txt \CatchFileDef\logfile{\removenumber{#1}.txt}{\endlinechar=-1} \typeout{\logfile}}

When called with \getlog{log123.456} this should output "log123.456 log.txt" and should print the contents of log.txt to my log file. The first part works correctly, i.e. if the second part is removed, it correctly outputs "log123.456 log.txt". However, once the second part is included, it breaks with the following error:
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
let 
l.11 \getlog{log123.456}
                      
! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
     ! LaTeX Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: xs_assign xs_expand_and_ass
l.11 \getlog{log123.456}
                      
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
let 
l.11 \getlog{log123.456}
                      
! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
     ! LaTeX Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: xs_assign xs_expand_and_ass
l.11 \getlog{log123.456}
                      
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
let 
l.11 \getlog{log123.456}
                      
! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
     ! LaTeX Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: xs_assign xs_expand_and_ass
l.11 \getlog{log123.456}
                      
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex)
\message {File ignored}
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

What is going wrong? Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\removenumber}[1]{\StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastchar]\StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\gobbled]\StrDel{\gobbled}{.}[\tempdelchar]\IfInteger{\lastchar}{\removenumber{\tempdelchar}}{#1\lastchar}}

\newcommand{\getlog}[1]{#1 \removenumber{#1}.txt \CatchFileDef\logfile{\removenumber{#1}.txt}{\endlinechar=-1} \typeout{\logfile}}

\begin{document}
\getlog{log123.456}
\end{document}

I'm not really looking for how my \removenumber macro can be rewritten. I'm sure it could be improved using some looping construct or maybe there's some macro which already does this. How can I simply pass the value of the output of some arbitrary macro A as an argument to macro B?
Really, my question is more general. I have been programming in many different languages for many years. Some languages, like C++, are more complex and have worse error messages than others. But one can always master techniques for debugging and general types of errors that occur. I have been using Latex on and off for about 6 years by this point. It normally works fine for the simple things, but the moment I try to do anything more interesting, more like programming, it breaks in some obscure way. What techniques can be used to debug this sort of thing? What "types of errors" occur? Do I basically have to understand in depth every package I use, so I can make my code interface properly with it?

Welcome to TeX.SX! I understand your comment "the moment ... it breaks in some obscure way", as I went through this years/decades ago. I think one of the main reasons for this experience is that TeX's concept of macro expansion is fundamentally different from conventional programming languages. Macro calls look like function calls, but they aren't. Re your problem: My guess is that it is an expansion issue, and it may be necessary to look into your definition of \removenumber, as it is not expandable (has side effects like defining something) and hence breaks as argument of \CatchFileDef.

xstring package functions are almost never expandable but (because of this) they have the option to save the result in a command so you can then use that command in an expandable context such as the filename argument. Or (simpler) use the expl3 string functions which are mostly expandable, and don't require loading a package.

Ok, thanks for the suggestions. Is "being expandable" something similar to being a pure function, but for macros? Re xstring not being expandable, I have used the optional output argument for each of my parts, but how can I do the same thing for my own macro (which combines multiple outputs)?
